# CASE WHEN logic issue in INSERT statment

Tags: sql-server, insert, case

I am writing an `INSERT`statement to a table that contains employee names assigned to various materials (articles) based on a "waterfall" logic if you will.  Essentially, I want the `CASE`statement below to set rules for assignment.  For example if the PO type is 05 and the stock category of the material is `LIKE` A60383% then assign the PO to AZ if those conditions aren't met then continue to the next logical text.  This is working fine except in cases of multi-line PO's.  It seems to be assigning correctly for only the first line - the next line it uses the logic further down the statement, specifically the business unit logic.  The business unit logic is correctly assigned but I want that first rule to take precedent for BOTH lines.  Any idea what I may be doing incorrectly?

**Here is an example of the output - the first employee assignment is correct because the stock category is A60385001 and that goes to MB the second line isn't following that logic though and is instead assigning to JLM because the article is in her business unit, that logic is further down though.  Causes this PO to show up in the report twice.**:

```
PO# Qty Article Description PO Created BY   BU  Date    Assigned Employee
282859618   109 CF0864  YG ZNE CH FZ HD LANGEJUL    App Kids    8/31/2017 0:00  MB
282859618   191 CF0864  YG ZNE CH FZ HD LANGEJUL    App Kids    8/31/2017 0:00  JLM


INSERT INTO SCM_PO_EMPLOYEE_NAME (PO_NUMBER, PO_ITEM_NUMBER, MATERIAL,PO_TYPE,BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE,TEAM_MEMBER_NAME)



      SELECT DISTINCT I.PO_NUMBER, 
                                                      I.PO_ITEM_NUMBER, 
                                                      I.MATERIAL,
                                                      H.PO_TYPE,
                                                      B.BU_CODE,

                                             CASE WHEN H.PO_TYPE IN ('05','07') -- Promo PO type - should be on both po type and stock category
                                                  AND  I.STOCK_CATEGORY LIKE ('A60383%') -- verify the stock category on the PROMO PO is in 3000
                                                  THEN 'AZ'
                                                  WHEN I.STOCK_CATEGORY = 'A60385001' -- retail to Michelle
                                                  THEN 'MB'
                                                  WHEN H.PO_TYPE = '02' -- miadidas PO type
                                                  THEN 'MB'
                                                  WHEN H.PO_TYPE = '03' -- B grade PO
                                                  THEN 'MH'
                                                  WHEN H.PO_TYPE = 'DB' -- dummy PO
                                                  THEN 'JLM'
                                                  WHEN H.PO_TYPE = '12'-- ISC -- Can be called out on the article level?
                                                  AND  M.DEPARTMENT = '01'-- division is ftw
                                                  THEN 'MZ'
                                                  WHEN H.PO_TYPE = '12'-- ISC
                                                  AND  M.DEPARTMENT = '02' -- division is app
                                                  THEN 'JLM'
                                                  WHEN I.MATERIAL IN ( SELECT ARTICLE
                                                                       FROM   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED.dbo.SCM_EMPLOYEE_ARTICLE A ) -- Check the Employee to article table next
                                                  THEN A.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME -- If the article is in the table then assign the employee from the employee to article table
                                                  WHEN M.BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE = B.BU_CODE -- if not use then go to the BU assignment (below)
                                                  THEN B.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME  -- Use the team member name from the Employee_BU table
                                                  ELSE 'NO_EMPLOYEE' -- check for misses
                                             END  AS   [TEAM_MEMBER_NAME]

                                      FROM   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_ITEM I 
                                      LEFT JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_HEADER H ON I.PO_NUMBER = H.PO_NUMBER 
                                      LEFT JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_MM_MATERIAL M ON I.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
                                      LEFT JOIN   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED.dbo.SCM_EMPLOYEE_ARTICLE A ON I.MATERIAL = A.ARTICLE
                                      LEFT JOIN   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED.dbo.SCM_EMPLOYEE_BU B ON B.BU_CODE = M.BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE

                                      WHERE H.VENDOR_NO <> '20800' --Exclude '20800' as a vendor!!
                                      AND   H.PO_TYPE <> '01';
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show an example of the multi-line PO formats and what it is returning and what you want it to return?

Comment: updated - the headers of the data output are a bit misaligned

Comment: I tried using MAX(I.PO_ITEM_NUMBER) as well with no luck - a bit more info - the PO can have more than one line but only one material - I would be fine with looking only at the first line

Comment: So the second row's `employee` is supposed to be `mb`? Your format is really messy and it's difficult to follow.

Comment: yes second row employee should be mb as well - the first logic needs to take precedent - apologies for the messy data insert

Comment: update - I rewrote to only insert where the PO item number is '1' - this seems to be working as per policy PO's will only ever have one material even if it is multi line PO.  Would still be interested in why the second line wasn't working properly  though